# Re-streaming RTMP stream

Tags: flash-media-server, rtmp

I have a set of local RTMP stream servers in my network, but I want them to be reachable outside. The bandwidth is too narrow to serve multiple clients on the streamservers of my network, so the idea is to pull the local RTMP streams on a computer serving as a gateway, which pushes them on his turn to a hosted streaming provider. It is not possible to let the sources of the stream push their stream directly to the server outside due to network policy restrictions.

Scheme of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
   Internal network                             |         External network 

   ------------              ------------                ----------------------- 
   | internal |      <----   |  Gateway |      ------>   | streamserver outside|
   | streams  |              ------------                -----------------------
   ------------                                 |                ^
                                                |                |
                                                |            -----------  
                                                |            | clients |
                                                |            -----------
```

My question now is: which application which can pull a live stream from an RTMP source (Flash Media Server) and push it to another one (Flash Media Server at hosting provider).

Comment: did you try wowza?

Answer (score 1):

You can set-up Wowza to accept RTMP connections which it will then pull from another origin source on-the-fly.

They call it live-repeater.

Answer (score 0):

VLC supports RTMP and is capable of re-streaming it in a variety of formats and protocols. See the [VLC documentation wiki page](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples) for details.